# "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined" instead of "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization"

Tags: javascript, uncaught-reference-error

In this simple code, since the variable b is a *let* variable and i am trying to log() its value, I was expecting a reference error that said: cannot access 'a' before initialization,

but instead i am getting the error:
*Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined*

```js
console.log(a);
let a=10;
var b=19;
```

[a screenshot of the code and the error-->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps70R.png)

i ran the same code in online js editors and they give the expected error, i am confused now  :
[the same code on an online editor with different error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asM8I.png)

Comment: How were you running the code?

Comment: @AndrewParks OP is aware of the hoisting. They are asking why they get different errors in different environments

Comment: @Bergi It seems like the first runtime is a browser (by the looks Chrome) and the online editor seems to use NodeJs to run the code. I would say the answer to OP's question comes down to how different runtimes handle/(respond to) this kind of error.

Comment: What tool is it that you're getting that first error in? It looks like a Chromium browser, but I don't get that result in Chromium browsers. I (correctly) get "before initialization" error instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm getting "*Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined*" when pasting the code in the devtools console

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, REPLs (as you know) are weird. But the OP's screenshot doesn't look like a REPL.

Comment: @​En_On - Please answer [my question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78132233/uncaught-referenceerror-a-is-not-defined-instead-of-referenceerror-cannot-a/78132373#comment137744459_78132233).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry I could not reply sooner due to personal problems. 
The environment I was coding in is the chrome dev tool's Snippet section. I was exploring stuff about the language.
ALSO,  Alex borodin's suggestions (can be found down below) seems to work for me, that is when I put BRACES in the GLOBAL SPACE, it seems to work (says: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization )
but without braces, the former unexpected error (ReferenceError: a is not defined ) is met. 
and I am still cant understand why that is.

Answer (score 1):

`ReferenceError: a is not defined` means that the identifier `a` isn't declared *at all* in the current scope. That's clearly not the case in the code you've shown, suggesting either that the error isn't from the code shown (prehaps a previous run?) or that the code is being executed in an unusual way, such as in a REPL like the browser console. REPLs often execute the code in a slightly different way than it would be if it were run as part of a program, so it's generally best not to worry too much about this kind of difference between a REPL and non-REPL environment. Your screenshot doesn't look like a REPL, though. Here's an example of "is not defined":

```js
console.log(a);
```

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization`¹ means that `a` **is** declared in the scope, but you tried to use it before it was initialized, when it was in the [Temporal Dead Zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz). That's the correct error for the code shown when executed in the normal way (not in a REPL), because `let a` exists in the same scope as the `console.log(a)` above it, and so the binding (variable) is created but not initialized before the `console.log` statement attempts to access it. Here's your code at global scope, making it easy for people to see that this is the correct error:

```js
console.log(a);
let a=10;
var b=19;
```

---

¹ That's V8's error (Chromium browsers, Node.js, Deno, ...). SpiderMonkey (in Firefox and such) says `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'a' before initialization` instead. JavaScriptCore (Safari, Bun) says `ReferenceError: Cannot access uninitialized variable.`

---

Another posted answer suggests that the difference relates to using a block statement or not using one, in part because MDN's page on the error is a bit misleading. That's incorrect, no block statement is required. (I raised [an issue for it](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/32630), and my [PR](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/32631) was merged; the page has been corrected now.) The specification's description of the relevant operation (`GetBindingValue`) of an environment record (in [this table](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-abstract-methods-of-environment-records)) makes no distinction between records created for blocks, specifically, vs. other kinds of environment records (global, modules, function, ...). To be sure, I've verified that the three major JavaScript engines (V8, SpiderMonkey, and JavaScriptCore) all behave as described above with the OP's code at global scope (no block statement required), giving the error about an uninitialized variable, not the "not defined" error. You can try a Chromium browser or Firefox on the snippet above to check for yourself. (You might be able to with Safari on a Mac as well. Unfortunately, iOS Safari just reports a script error. I have verified it by directly executing JavaScriptCore, since I don't have a Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [error docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init) it `happens within any block statement`

Since you don't have block statement, JS fires another error.

[image]

I suppose that in online editor, the code is executed by another code, so there could be block statement outside the "file".

Comment: This is incorrect. "Block" in this context includes global scope (and module scope). This is not why the user is getting different messages.

Comment: They say explicitly about "block statement" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block Not about scopes. So it works as documented.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder MDN writes "block statement" though. But I can't vouch for the correctness of that documentation…

Comment: @AlexBorodin - Sorry, I didn't catch MDN literally said "block statement." My bad. MDN is wrong sometimes, and it appears to be here. Try executing the OP's code at global scope in any of the major JavaScript engines. **All** of them will complain about using an uninitialized variable, not that it isn't defined. (Note that executing code at global scope in Node.js is tricky, since it defaults to modules. The easiest way is to redirect: `node < thefile.js`.)

Comment: I tried `node < file.js` from cmd and got `Cannot access 'a' before initialization`.

Comment: @qrsngky - Exactly, that's the correct error for the OP's code, even without a block statement. Unfortunately, this answer is incorrect. It's understandable that Alex would be misled by MDN's error, but it's easy to prove -- as you did -- that it *is* an error. (It's also clear from the specification, but the spec is *really* hard to understand as a casual user.)

Comment: In Firefox, it's `console: Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'a' before initialization`. So it seems that only Chromium-based console gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`? (I tried it from this site: I pressed F12 and pasted the code in the console. On Windows)

Comment: @qrsngky - The wording varies (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78132373/157247)), but the point is that none of them give "a is not defined," which is a *different* error that the code in the question will not produce in a normal environment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I found one of the environment/settings that gave "a is not defined", actually. It's from Chromium as I described above, so it applies to both Chrome and Edge in Windows. The snippet in the other answer gave `"Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization"` which is a different error. I wonder if it's because the snippet needs a "try/catch" block in order to produce `Error: { ... , "colno": 21} `

Comment: @qrsngky - Chromium-based browsers will not give `a is not defined` with the code in the question unless you paste it into the REPL, which is not a standard environment. Try the snippets in my answer in Chrome and Edge, for example. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: @qrsngky - Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVovl.png

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "Pasting it into the REPL" was exactly what I did to get that other error. But only in Chrome/Edge, not Firefox. And I think I misunderstood how snippets worked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "*It's also clear from the specification*" - I don't think the spec details the error message, it just requires any `ReferenceError` to be thrown.

Comment: @Bergi - I meant it's clear from the specification that the same error is thrown for a TDZ issue whether or not a block statement is used to create the environment record. As you say, the spec doesn't dictate error messages.

Answer (score -3):

The reason you're getting a Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined error instead of the expected cannot access 'a' before initialization is due to a difference in how let and var declarations are hoisted in JavaScript.

When you use let to declare a variable, the variable is hoisted to the top of its block scope, but it is not initialized until the actual declaration statement is encountered in the code. That's why you get a ReferenceError when you try to access the variable before its declaration.

On the other hand, when you use var to declare a variable, it is hoisted to the top of its function or global scope, and it's initialized with undefined at that point. Therefore, accessing a var variable before its declaration results in undefined rather than a ReferenceError.